# Base virtual "binded to object" function is called when overridden exists

Tags: c++, stl

I would like the `notifyAll` to bind an overridden child method to the object stored as parent referrence. Despite inheritance, the base method is still performed. The compiler seems can't see the overload or treats vector elements as non-reference objects. I can't find my bad in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class Observer {
public:
    virtual void onNewGame() {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
};

class Npc: public Observer {
public:
    virtual void onNewGame() {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
};

class Notifier {
public:
    void attach(Observer & observer) {
        this->observers.push_back(std::ref(observer));
    }
    void notifyNewGame() {
        this->notifyAll(&Observer::onNewGame);
    }
    void notifyAll(void(Observer::*eventMethod)(void)) {
        for (Observer & observer : this->observers)
            std::bind(eventMethod, observer)();
    }
    std::vector <std::reference_wrapper <Observer>> observers;
};

int main() {
    Npc npc;
    Notifier notifier;
    notifier.attach(npc);
    notifier.notifyNewGame();
}
```

I can't use `std::bind` with `&Npc::onNewGame` beacuse several classes inherit ftom the `Observer`.
Output:
`virtual void Observer::onNewGame()`
but I expect:
`virtual void Npc::onNewGame()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `std::bind()`. It is all but obsolete. (Prefer lambdas instead.)

Second, if you call it directly instead of `std::bind()`, it will work:

```cpp
(observer.*eventMethod)();
```

See it live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c5d56dd81f0b83d)</kbd>, where the output is the desired:

```
virtual void Npc::onNewGame()
```

Alternately, if you have C++17 support, you could use `std::invoke()`, per this [C++ FAQ on calling member functions indirectly](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#macro-for-ptr-to-memfn).

You might consider using a high-quality observer library like [Boost.Signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/signals2.html) instead of rolling your own. If you do need to roll your own, consider using `std::function` as its foundation.

PS, Style tips:

1. You don't need all the `this->` that are sprinkled throughout this code. Maybe they come from a more complicated context where they are needed, but as written, they are redundant.
2. Prefer replacing `virtual` in non-base classes with `override` to help the compiler to help you avoid errors.
3. Prefer `const`-correctness by adding `const` to functions like `Notifier`'s `notifyNewGame()` and `notifyAll()` that don't modify member data.

Answer (score 2):

`std::bind` does not store a reference to the object, so you're getting a slice of it.
The immediate fix is to use `std::ref` again:

```
std::bind(eventMethod, std::ref(observer))()
```

but the `bind` is an unnecessary indirection, and you can accomplish the same more directly:

```
(observer.*eventMethod)()
```

or use `std::function`:

```
void notifyNewGame() {
    notifyAll([](Observer& o) { o.onNewGame(); } );
}

void notifyAll(std::function<void(Observer&)> fn) {
     std::for_each(observers.begin(), observers.end(), fn); 
}
```